# Excel VBA Find data in two columns on a single row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make this code find a row where column V is not equal to "Y" or "L" AND column A is not blank.  I think I'm overdoing it a bit, I'm sure there is an easier way to check both cells on the row.

```
Sub EndMove()
Dim Col1 As Integer, Col2 As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String, currentRowValue2 As String

Col1 = 22
Col2 = 1
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Col1).End(xlUp).row

For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, Col1).Value
    If currentRowValue <> "y" Or currentRowValue <> "l" Then
    currentRowValue2 = Cells(currentRow, Col2).Value
    If Not IsEmpty(currentRowValue2) Then
    Cells(currentRow, Col1).Select
    MsgBox "Move this?"
End If
End If
Next
```

End Sub

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the data when  you find it?  Ie., Count it? Sum it? Return a value?

Comment: I need to select the cell in column A then call a sub.

Comment: @Bofett maybe you should explain more about what your code is meant to do (and possibly the other sub). You do not need to `Select` anything as stated in my comment. Chances are, you are just using `Select` as a middle operator. You already have an answer to your question here so your next problem deserves a new question imo.

Comment: @urdearboy, you are right.  I appreciate your help, this works perfect.  I will work on the section and start a new question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I changed `currentrow` to `i` since it is easier to use multiple times. You should also qualify your sheet. Anytime you are referring to an object on the target sheet, qualify it with `ws`

It's also worth nothing that this is case sensitive. I.E. `Y` <> `y`. If you want this to ignore case you can put `Option Compare Text` above `Sub EndMove`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub EndMove()
Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

rowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'i refers to row number
For i = 11 To rowCount
    If ws.Range("V" & i) <> "Y" And ws.Range("V" & i) <> "L" Then
        If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
            'Do what with row i?
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

You could also combine all 3 of your criteria into one line like so

```
For i = 11 To rowCount
    If ws.Range("V" & i) <> "Y" And ws.Range("V" & i) <> "L" And ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        'Do what with row i?
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Much better, thanks!  Can you please help me with ignoring case?  I'd like it to look for upper and lower case.  Also, is there an easy way to start looking at row 11 rather than the beginning?  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want to know if it is Y, y, L, or l? If so, I addressed that in the solution. Add `Option Compare Text` at the top and it will treat upper case and lower case equally

Comment: Updated to start at row 11. Just change `For i = 1 to` to `For i = 11 to `. Again, `i` and `currentrow` are the same. Every time you see `i`, think *row number*

Comment: Thanks again,  I need to select the cell in column A then call a sub.

Comment: You do not need to `Select`! What do you really need to do?

Comment: I say that because i'm guessing you want to `Select` a cell or row and then `Copy` or `Delete` it. Either way, chances are you are trying to use `Select` as a middle man which is not necessary. It actually leads to problems.